# Why does applying float to input make preceeding span move few pixels up?

Tags: css, radio-button, css-float

I know this is very simple case, but it gives me serious headache. Why in this very, very simple example does floating the radio cause preceeding span to move few pixels up? Can this be prevented somehow?

OK, to clarify: `float: right` is commented out so you can uncomment it in jsfiddle and see the "Text" position change (like it gets centered or applied margin-bottom).

```
HTML
<span class="wrap">
    <span>Text</span>
    <input type="radio" class="myRadio"></input>
<span>

CSS
.myRadio{
   /*float: right;*/
}
.wrap{
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m4o4epw0/2/

I always though that if you apply `float: right` to inline-block element preceeding inline-block element does not need to be moved.

Comment: There's no `#float` property in CSS. It looks the same even without that property. What do you exactly mean?

Comment: I thought it is pretty clear. Obviously not, so I clarified it as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay fine. Now I understand. It is not *preceding `<span>` moves up*. The reason is, the `<input>` element, when it has the DOM space (no float and static position), it has a height higher than `span` and that the `span` is vertically bottom aligned.

When you give a `float: right` or any other float or position for that instance, it doesn't take up the DOM space and you see that that `<span>` takes its own height.

You can make the `float`ed element take DOM Space by using `overflow: hidden` on the parent as shown below.

Check out the examples here:

```css
.wrap {width: 75px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #999;}
.float .myRadio {float: right;}
.ovh {overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<h4>Without Float</h4>
<span class="wrap">
  <span>Text</span>
  <input type="radio" class="myRadio" />
</span>

<h4>With Float</h4>
<span class="wrap float">
  <span>Text</span>
  <input type="radio" class="myRadio" />
</span>

<h4>With Float</h4>
<span class="wrap float ovh">
  <span>Text</span>
  <input type="radio" class="myRadio" />
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the explanation I was looking for.